# Non de-batching messages in spring amqp

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I'm using `BatchingRabbitTemplate` to send messages in a batch to amqp endpoint. Now, on the other receiving end, I can use `@RabbitListener` to receive messages, but my problem is that messages are automatically de-batched so I cannot use `@RabbitHandler public void receive (List<SomeObject> so)`. Is there any simpler way of non-de-batching messages except me doing this:

`@RabbitListener(..., containerFactory = "nonDeBatchingContainerFactory")`

```
@Bean
public RabbitListenerContainerFactory nonDeBatchingContainerFactory(){
    SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
    factory.setDeBatchingEnabled(false);
    factory.setMessageConverter(jackson2JsonMessageConverter());
    factory.setAfterReceivePostProcessors(new NonDeBatchingMessagePostProcessor(jackson2JsonMessageConverter()));
    return factory;
    }
```

and then implementing this post-processor (that is more or less copy of existing code for de-batching).

```
public class NonDeBatchingMessagePostProcessor implements MessagePostProcessor {

    private MessageConverter payloadConverter;

    public NonDeBatchingMessagePostProcessor(MessageConverter payloadConverter) {
        this.payloadConverter = payloadConverter;
    }

    @Override
    public Message postProcessMessage(Message message) throws AmqpException {
        Object batchFormat = message.getMessageProperties().getHeaders().get(MessageProperties.SPRING_BATCH_FORMAT);
        if (MessageProperties.BATCH_FORMAT_LENGTH_HEADER4.equals(batchFormat)) {
            List<? super Object> aggregatedObjects = new ArrayList<>();
            ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(message.getBody());
            MessageProperties messageProperties = message.getMessageProperties();
            String singleObjectTypeId = messageProperties.getHeaders().get(DEFAULT_CLASSID_FIELD_NAME).toString();
            messageProperties.getHeaders().remove(MessageProperties.SPRING_BATCH_FORMAT);
            while (byteBuffer.hasRemaining()) {
                int length = byteBuffer.getInt();
                if (length < 0 || length > byteBuffer.remaining()) {
                    throw new ListenerExecutionFailedException("Bad batched message received",
                            new MessageConversionException("Insufficient batch data at offset " + byteBuffer.position()),
                            message);
                }
                byte[] body = new byte[length];
                byteBuffer.get(body);
                messageProperties.setContentLength(length);
                // Caveat - shared MessageProperties.
                Message fragment = new Message(body, messageProperties);
                Object singleObject = this.payloadConverter.fromMessage(fragment);
                aggregatedObjects.add(singleObject);
            }
            Message aggregatedMessages = this.payloadConverter.toMessage(aggregatedObjects, messageProperties);
            aggregatedMessages.getMessageProperties().getHeaders().put(DEFAULT_CONTENT_CLASSID_FIELD_NAME, singleObjectTypeId);
            return aggregatedMessages;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I need this use case in order to receive all messages in batch on the rabbit and then do bulk indexing in elastic search. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be a bit easier to do the batching at the producing application level (send a `List<SomeObject>`) rather than using the batching template. Then you won't need anything at all on the consumer side.

Comment: shouldn't this be default behavior of batching template? then depending  on method signature (list or single object) it can determine handler method?

Comment: Unfortunately, the debatching is done at a much lower level - the listener container doesn't know anything about its `MessageListener` - we could consider adding a flag to the container "don't debatch" and then add code similar to yours in the `MessagingMessageListenerAdapter`. Feel free to open a [new feature JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP). And contributions are always welcome :)